# Null reference exception in entity navigation

Tags: entity-framework

I have the following EF structure:

[image]

I want to get name of the every user who attended to a meeting:

```
using(var ctx = new MyContext())
{
    var meeting = (from row in ctx.Meetings.Include("MeetingMessages").Include("MeetingUsers")
            where row.mId == 1
            select row).FirstOrDefault();

    foreach(var meetingUser in meeting.MeetingUsers)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(meetingUser.User.Name); //<== exception
    }
}
```

I'm getting `NullReferenceException` in `meetingUser.User.Name` line because `meetingUser.User` instance is null. I can't add any `.Include()` to `Meeting` because there are no relations in between. Is there a way to load it without doing `meetingUser.UserReference.Load()` in foreach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to project:

```
using(var ctx = new MyContext())
{
    var meeting = (from row in ctx.Meetings
                   where row.mId == 1
                   select new
                   {
                       Meeting = row,
                       MeetingUsers = row.MeetingUsers,
                       Users = from u in row.MeetingUsers
                               select u.User
                   }).First();

    foreach(var meetingUser in meeting.MeetingUsers)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(meetingUser.User.Name); //<== exception
    }
}
```

Comment: That was certainly an eye opener. Thank you.